# Wraping Author names in LREC template

Tags: author

We have a rather long list of name to add to a paper and are having trouble with the formatting.

The template is for LREC [available here](http://lrec2018.lrec-conf.org/en/submission/), the document class and packages it uses are

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lrec}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{languageresource}{Language Resources}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{soul}
% for eps graphics

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xstring}
```

When we try the below the names appear on one line extending way past the papers right margin

```
\name{FNameA SNameA, FNameB SNameB, FNameC SNameC, FNameD SNameD, FNameE SNameE}
```

If we try the below the `\newline` is ignored and the names extend past the right margin.

```
\name{FNameA SNameA, FNameB SNameB, FNameC SNameC, \newline 
FNameD SNameD, FNameE SNameE,}
```

If we try the below, the names on the second line lose the formatting of the first line

```
\name{FNameA SNameA, FNameB SNameB, FNameC SNameC, \\ 
FNameD SNameD, FNameE SNameE,}
```

if I try the below it ignores the first \name { } and renders the second

```
\name{FNameA SNameA, FNameB SNameB, FNameC SNameC} 
\name{ FNameD SNameD, FNameE SNameE,}
```

Comment: Please tell us more about the "LREC template": is it a LaTeX document class, a LaTeX package, or something else? Is it available online?

Comment: Deadline day! The `.sty`, `.bst` and a template are available on http://lrec2018.lrec-conf.org/en/submission/authors-kit/.

Comment: Quick fix: `\name{\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering Author1, Author2, Author3, Author4, Author5, Author6, Author7, Author8, Author9, Author10, Author11}}`

Answer (score 2):

The LREC template provides the answer, as a comment within the lrec.sty file (lines 68sq):

```
% If the names do not fit well on one line use
%
%         \name{Firstname1 Surname1 \\ {\bf \large Firstname2 Surname2} \\
%         ... \\ {\bf \large FirstnameN SurnameN }}
%
```

I tried it and it works Just Fine.

It's an old question, but one which may well become topical again as the deadline for submissions to LREC 2022 approaches :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you so much for the welcome, and for the tutoring! :+1: After benefiting from others' help for years, I look forward to making a contribution if I can.

Comment: Note that in general the use of `\bf` for boldface is deprecated (as is `\it` for italics, `\sc` for smallcaps), and `\textbf{...}` should be used instead. This is of course not Alexis' fault, however it may cause trouble in edge cases (compare `\bf John Smith \sc III}` and `\textbf{John Smith \textsc{III}}` for example, where in the first case the smallcaps are not bold and in the second case they are).

Comment: Thanks, I'll forward this observation to the colleagues maintaining the template!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the hint, I just modified the file to include the new command: `\bfseries` instead of `\bf`;

I will be in touch directly;

Khalid Choukri for LREC2022.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/217883)